# CoreData unable to generate getters and setters

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a class that has a manual definition. This can be seen below.

```
class NewsFeedResponse: NSManagedObject, Cachable {

    @NSManaged var id: String?
    @NSManaged var cachedAt: Date?
    @NSManaged var featuredArticles: Array<FeaturedArticle>?
    @NSManaged var learningMaterials: Array<LearningMaterial>?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case featuredArticles
        case learningMaterials
    }

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        super.init(entity: NewsFeedResponse.entity(), insertInto: CoreDataManager.shared.getContext())
        do {
            self.cachedAt = Date()
            self.featuredArticles = try container.decode(Array<FeaturedArticle>?.self, forKey: .featuredArticles)
            self.learningMaterials = try container.decode(Array<LearningMaterial>?.self, forKey: .learningMaterials)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { }
}
```

Both the featuredArticles and learningMaterials have a one to many relationship in both directions within the coredata model. If I change Array to Set, this will not crash the only problem with using a Set is that they're not ordered like Arrays, so the order of data is inconsistent. It's also worth noting i've not marked the class with @objc since if I do the object doesn't seem to be persisted which is why it doesn't have this tag.

Beside that whenever I run my application now I'm getting the following crash.

```
2019-08-20 09:51:07.265011+0100 [89304:24860419] [error] error: Property 'featuredArticles' is marked copy on class ‘XXXXX.NewsFeedResponse'.  Cannot generate a copying setter method for NSManagedObject's to-one relationship.
CoreData: error: Property 'featuredArticles' is marked copy on class 'XXXXXXX.NewsFeedResponse'.  Cannot generate a copying setter method for NSManagedObject's to-one relationship.
2019-08-20 09:51:07.265235+0100 XXXXXXX[89304:24860419] -[XXXXXXX.NewsFeedResponse setFeaturedArticles:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002d8afd0
2019-08-20 09:51:07.270994+0100 XXXXXXX[89304:24860419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XXXXXXX.NewsFeedResponse setFeaturedArticles:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002d8afd0'
```

I'm unsure on how to write these setters that coredata is complaining about.

Comment: But a one-to-one relationship shouldn't be defined as an Array (or Set) in either entity, what am I missing here?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson when i change the type to one to many i'm getting the following error. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "featuredArticles"; desired type = NSSet; given type = _TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageC18HealthAssuredAdHoc15FeaturedArticle_$;

Comment: Well what is it supposed to be design wise, to one or to many? That must be the important question. Personally I have never tried to change the type of a relationship in a entity class and always kept my to-many as Set

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is meant to be a to-many and I did have it as a Set before and it was working fine, the only issue is with using a Set is that they don't maintain order so when the app is loading content either from the service or offline the order of the content is inconsistent, which is why i'm trying to use an array

Comment: Fine but please don't write one to one then if it is one to many. Also note that in the sql world there is no defined order in a table, you need to define what order you want by using ORDER BY in your query. To me it sounds like you are just creating trouble for yourself by trying to change the type.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Fair enough, I have updated and changed the typo in the question. See the thing is from the service there is nothing to define the order by i.e. an id, which is why I wanted to change it to an Array so it would automatically be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

To-many relationships **must** be declared as (preferable non-optional) `Set` or `NSSet`

```
@NSManaged var featuredArticles: Set<FeaturedArticle>
@NSManaged var learningMaterials: Set<LearningMaterial>
```

If you need an order there are three options:

1. Declare both types as `NSOrderedSet` (there is no Swift equivalent) and check the *Arrangement: Ordered* checkbox in the model.
2. Add a computed property or a method to return a sorted array.
3. Fetch the articles and materials for the specific `NewsFeedResponse` with an appropriate predicate and sort descriptor.